# How to account for baud speed in logic analyzer

Tags: digital-logic, stm32, uart

I'm an utter newbie awkwardly stumbling along, so I apologize if this should be obvious somehow.

I have a FTDI 232R UART hooked up to a "blue pill", and I'm send my first bytes along. I have `screen` open in a terminal to follow along, but it's just gibberish. No problem, I hook up a logic analyzer (shiny new Saleae Logic 8) and take a peek at the signal. Slowing the baud rate down to `100` on the STM32 I see that my "Hello World\n\r" message isn't getting read even close to the right timing by the Saleae.

I have seen that the receiving device should be sampling maybe between 8x - 16x the rate to hit the middle of the pulse, so I try setting it to `800` and try again. Better, but no dice. After some experimentation I finally get the signal loud and clear by setting the Saleae to `1140` and it looks like `1139` would have been optimal. I set the baud rate on `screen` to `1140`, but still gibberish.

I'm sure I can fiddle around to get this to line up, but I'm wondering, how should I know what multiple to use to begin with? Is it just experiment until it captures it correctly? Is there a resource that could help me get over the hump? (I'm new enough that I don't even know where to go to get knowledge.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you use a serial port for the first time, a baudrate different then expected happens often. The most likely cause is that the clock, from which you derive the baudrate is different from what you thought it was. You have to read the datasheet very, very carefully and look for e.g. pre-dividers, scaling factors etc. Sometime you have to check the CPU clock section. (Second cause is not using the baudrate formula correct). I still have some code somewhere with the comment' Baudrate out by factor 2 but don't know why"

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that there is a baud rate formula. I might have mentioned that I'm not in college for this or anything, I'm just curious to learn it so I picked up some stuff and just started reading through Geoffrey Browns *Discovering the STM32*. Is there a book/web site that serves as a decent primer to get this sort of info?

Comment: What is a "blue pill?"

Comment: It's what seems to be the common name for the STM32F103C8T6, which is a very cheap and tiny STM32 board with a Cortex-M3.

Comment: @alex.forencich Oh come on! Didn't you watch any movies in the last 18 years?

Answer (score 2):

The exact baud rate can be measured with the time interval of 1 bit using a calculator.  Multiples of 1200 are standard and ought to be within 50ppm but only need to be < ~10% -1/16th of a  bit to work with 1start+8data+1stop=10 bits.

Start with 9600 which is default then see how fast you can go with short leads.

RS232 uses 1.4V (2diode drop) thresholds which is identical to TTL but is inverted to TTL which uses negative logic levels.

Specs are ...
 UART interface support for 7 or 8 data bits, 1  or2 stop bits and odd/even/mark/space/parity

 Data transfer rates from 300 baud to 3 Mbaud at TTL levels.

So if using TTL set logic analyzer accordingly for TTL UART.

This what your fine manual has to say...

> Autobaud accomplishes this by simply running the analyzer twice when you save the settings. First, it runs the analyzer using the baud rate set in the analyzer settings (default 9600). While it's running, it keeps track of the narrowest pulse in the entire capture. Then, it sets the baud rate accordingly, assuming that the narrowest pulse is exactly 1 bit wide.
>
> If the narrowest pulse width is only 1 sample wide, the autobaud system will fail and not attempt to adjust the baud rate. That can happen when not sampling fast enough or when there is noise in the capture.
>
> If the narrowest pulse is within 5% of the user-entered baud rate, it will not attempt to adjust the baud rate.
>
> If neither condition is true, the software will automatically change the baud rate to the new setting and re-run the analyzer.
>
> To see if autobaud worked, re-open the analyzer settings. If the baud rate didn't change, then one of the above two conditions must have prevented it from working.

Comment: Thank you! I find this very helpful. It actually was good enough that I now have everything showing up as expected in the terminal as well.

Comment: You might want to add that 0xAA and 0x55 have alternating zeroes and ones.

Comment: next time , read the manual, although , I never (rarely do) when you expect it to be intuititive, but work hard and your will get intuition too.